# Why does $A_\infty=\bigcup_{n\geq 5}^{\infty} \,A_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

My question is: why does $$A_\infty=\bigcup_{n\geq 5}^{\infty} \,A_n \,\,?$$

Doesn't $A_{\infty}$ contain (an isomorphic copy of) $A_4$, which is not a simple group? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I just haven't been able to see it. This comes from here: [Is the question phrased properly? and is my proof correct? (An infinite alternating group is simple)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079228/is-the-question-phrased-properly-and-is-my-proof-correct-an-infinite-alternat?rq=1).

Comment: Well, $A_{5}$ already contains $A_{4}$.

Comment: I think I see. Does that mean that $A_\infty = \bigcup_{n\geq k}^{\infty} A_n$ for any $k\geq 5$? I feel my confusion came from not understanding why 5 was chosen in particular.

Comment: Yes because you can show that $A_{n-1}<A_n$. $A_5$ is the smallest simple alternating group (and also smallest simple non-abelian group).

Comment: Starting from 5 is  to emphasize that $A_\infty$ is a union of finite simple groups.